# Finding an accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer

How do I go about finding/calculating the specifications of an accelerometer that can measure vibrations upto 2kHz and deflections upto 2mm?

EDIT: After calculating and obtaining 16000g's worth of acceleration, I consulted my mentor and it seems like we might not experience 2mm of deflections at 2kHz. However, now the problem becomes how to estimate what deflections we will see at that frequency if we use PL 140 actuators from PI and place them on the panel?

https://www.piceramic.com/en/products/piezoceramic-actuators/bender-actuators/pl112-pl140-picma-bender-103000/

Comment: It seems to me that you have defined them already a lot better than many questions that have been asked on the site. Edit your question to explain the application a bit (single axis, bandwidth, etc.) and work out what acceleration you will need at that frequency and deflection.

Comment: First you'd need to calculate the expected acceleration from the deflection, frequency, and expected wave shape.  Then go to a parametric search, both by acceleration range, and reading frequency if you want to dry to do a reasonable job of sampling the acceleration waveform.

Comment: oh, and in practice it's also often important what kind of output signal your sensor has – ie. whether it modulates a voltage or a current, or gives digital readings, or...

Comment: are you asking us to calculate the peak acceleration due to a 2mm amplitude at 2kHz?

Comment: @Transistor So using the formula that a = (2*pi^2*F^2*D)/G , I get a = 16102.66m/s^2 which seems too high. I am putting an accelerometer on a panel that will be vibrated upto 2kHz of frequency and we will see deflections upto 2mm which we want to measure.

Comment: I'm with @Neil_UK. Wouldn't want to get near a panel vibrating @ 2 kHz, 2mm amplitude without serious ear protection. That's a tough spec to meet.

Comment: Look at various microphone mechanisms and it shouldn't be hard to come up with a suitable sensor, there are likely already some sold as accelerometers.  But acceleration may not be the best way to measure deflection.  Could you use an LED strobe to light it at the extremes of position and simply look with a camera?  Or bounce a laser off of it and measure the elongation of the deflected spot into a line?  *Or you can just measure necessary displacement distance of the operator into the parking lot and down the street*

Comment: @YuktiKathuria: According to http://www.amesweb.info/SinusMotion/SinusMotion.aspx your calculation is correct. What on earth are you doing to generate this?

Comment: The linked web page for that piezo actuator lists its dimensions as 45 mm x 11 mm and a "blocking force" of +/- 0.5 N. If this means that 0.5 N is enough to stop it then it seems to me that an accelerometer may load it considerably as will whatever it is driving. That +/-1000 µm displacement probably only occurs with no load. (I know close to nothing about these types of devices!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accelerometers are specified by the maximum accelerations they can measure.  You therefore have to calculate what acceleration is represented by moving 2 mm at 2 KHz.

From your description, 2 mm is the peak to peak magnitude of the 2 kHz oscillation.  Acceleration is the second derivative of displacement.  The displacement is (1 mm)sin(2Πt 2000/s).  Take the second derivative, which will be another sine.  The peak of that is the ±magnitude the accelerometer needs to be able to measure.  Acclerometers are often specified in g instead of m/s<sup>2</sup> or the like.  1 g = 9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>.

### Added

Now I have time to show the calculations.  The equation for displacement is:

Disp = (1 mm)sin(2Πt 2000/s)

First derivative:

Speed = (12.57x10<sup>3</sup> mm/s)cos(2Πt 2000/s)

Second derivative:

Acc = -(158x10<sup>6</sup> mm/s<sup>2</sup>)sin(2Πt 2000/s)

The accelleration range is therefore ±158x10<sup>6</sup> mm/s<sup>2</sup> = ±158x10<sup>3</sup> m/s<sup>2</sup>.

±(158x10<sup>3</sup> m/s<sup>2</sup>)/(9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>g) = ±16.1x10<sup>3</sup> g.

Comment: I get an extremely large amount of g's. Just the magnitude is 315827.34. It's about 32227.28g. I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @Yuk: I just realized I made a mistake since it's 2 mm peak to peak, so 1 mm peak (now fixed above).  Still that only accounts for a factor of 2.  I don't have time now to go thru the numbers myself.

Comment: The 16000g are correct.